# Symfony like view helpers in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Symfony has this:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/components/templating.html#helpers

I can't find laravels equivalent? What do people use in Laravel in place of this?

I myself have tried creating custom helpers.php, which is good for some use cases I guess, but now I'm at the point, where I would like something a little bit more structured.

I am thinking maybe Facades would be be good option?

Is there anything else I could take a look at for Symfony's template helpers equivalent in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the closest thing to this is directives. It allows you to add new methods to blade that you can use.
[Can find the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#extending-blade)

You can also add a new facade if you need something more complex that will be accessable from the view layer as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Directives definitely good for some things, but ultimately feels a bit like helper functions. but thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @galdikas this is the solution, what are you exactly looking for? Maybe you want a [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#view-composers)?

Comment: @matiaslauriti nah. I guess I'll just stick with Facades for my current use case. Thanks everyone

Comment: @galdikas you can share the code you are trying to run as an example so we can truly help you in that case